# Exact Definition of an Open Covering for Topology

Tags: general-topology

**Definition 0:** Let $Y\subseteq X$. Let $\lbrace A_i \rbrace_{i\in I}=\lbrace B_\alpha\subseteq X\mid\alpha\in J \rbrace$. Thus, $\lbrace A_i \rbrace_{i\in I}$ **covers** $Y$ iff $Y\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in I}A_\alpha$.

**Definition 1:** Let $(X, T)$ be a topological space. Now, let $Y\subseteq X$. Let $T_1=\lbrace Y\cap U\mid U\in T \rbrace$. Thus, $T_1$ on $Y$ is **induced by the topology** $T$ on $X$ which yields a topological space $(Y, T_1)$.

**Definition 2:** Now, let $X$ be topological space. Let $Y\subseteq X$. A covering $\lbrace A_\alpha \rbrace_{\alpha \in I}$ of $Y$ is said to be an **open covering** of $Y$ iff $\forall \alpha \in I$, "$A_\alpha$ is an open subset of $X$".

> **Question:** Saying "$A_\alpha$ is an open subset of $X$" is confusing me, because there are multiple possibilities where the open subsets of $X$ could come from. Instead of saying "$A_\alpha$ is an open subset of $X$" which option below $\textbf{(A.)}$, $\textbf{(B.)}$, or $\textbf{(C.)}$ is it?
>
> $\textbf{(A.)}$ "$A_\alpha$ is an element in the topology $T_1$ on $Y$ where $T_1$ on $Y$ is induced
>
> $\text{  }$ by the topology $T$ of $X$ (aka $A_\alpha\in T_1$)"
>
> $\textbf{(B.)}$ "$A_\alpha$ is an element in the topology of $X$ (aka $A_\alpha\in T$)"
>
> $\textbf{(C.)}$ "$A_\alpha$ is an either of these topologies (it doesn't matter)"

Comment: with your definition of an open covering I do not see any ambiguity and (B) is the correct answer.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, because the open sets in $T_1$ are subsets of $X$. Also, the open subsets in $T$ are subsets of $X$. I thought the statement was a lot less general in the way that $A_\alpha$ is an "open subset" of $X$ would be synonymous with the "open subsets of $T_1$" as there are two possibly different open sets here as there are two topologies. Either way, thank you for your help!

Comment: I guess I am still confused after the answers. Should the definition of an open covering be $B$ irregardless of the definition of covering?

Comment: When discussing only the single topology $T$ on $X, $ the phrases  "$A_{\alpha}$ is an open subset of $X$" and "$A_\alpha$ is open  in $X$" both mean $A_{\alpha} \in T.$.... Some of the "traditional" jargon in topology can seem confusing or ambiguous. From a set-theoretic perspective I would rather  just say "$A_{\alpha} \in T$".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it can be either A or B but if we go by the second definition you provided, it is B:

Now in order for it to be A, then any question must specify where those open sets lie. Since your definition says that they are open in $X$ then so it is. If it doesn't specify, but you're given a topology only on $X$ it should be safe to assume that $A_{\alpha}$ are open in $X$. Else, it should specify that it's an open cover of $Y$ in the $T_1$ topology.

Comment: "A **covering** $\{A_{\alpha}\}_{\alpha \in I}$ of $Y$ is said to be an open covering...." so I guess the integral part you mention is hidden in the definition of 'covering'.

Comment: I am going to add the definition of a covering. I did not know that part was dependent on that.

Comment: I added "definition 0" of a covering in the question. Does that mean it is still either $A$ or $B$?

Comment: @W.G. as I mentioned above; in your second definition you explicitly say that $A_{\alpha}$ is open in $X$. Therefore going by that alone the answer is B.

Comment: Cool. I got it! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

An open covering of a *subset* $Y \subset X$ is in fact a family of open $A_\alpha \in T$ such that $Y \subset \bigcup_\alpha A_\alpha$. The subspace topology of $Y$ is irrelevant here. This means that (B.) is correct.

To see the difference between your conditions (A.) - (C.) let us say more precisely that $\mathfrak{A} = \lbrace A_\alpha \rbrace$ is an open covering of $Y$ in the space $X$.

The $A_\alpha \cap Y$ are open in the subspace topology $T_1$ on $Y$ and form an open covering of $Y$ in the space $Y$ which we denote by $\mathfrak{A} \cap Y$.

Moreover, if you have any open covering $\mathfrak{B} = \lbrace B_\alpha \rbrace$ of $Y$ in the space $Y$ (which corrresponds to (A.)), then each $B_\alpha$ has the form $A_\alpha \cap Y$ with an open $A_\alpha \in T$. Therefore the $A_\alpha$ form an open covering $\mathfrak{A}$ of $Y$ in the space $X$ such that $\mathfrak{B} = \mathfrak{A} \cap Y$. Note that $\mathfrak{A}$ is in general not uniquely determined by $\mathfrak{B}$.

Condition (C.) is definitely never used.

Comment: Would this work for a definition then? I just want to get my notation down with this using that definition. Let $(X, T)$ be a topological space. Let $Y\subseteq X$. Lastly, let $Y\subseteq \bigcup_{\alpha \in I} A_\alpha$. We say $\lbrace A_\alpha \rbrace_{\alpha \in I}$ is an open covering of $Y$ iff $\forall \alpha \in I, A_\alpha \in T$.

Comment: Yes, that's it.

Comment: I appreciate your help too! Wish I could give multiple right answers for certain questions.